# can you explain this logic

Tags: python

explain this logic

```
input:ABDEF
output:GFECB 

input:ZZZ
output:AAA
```

write a program this logic

Comment: `if value == 'ABDEF': print('GFECB')`. Pretty logical. ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
A B D E F
1 2 4 5 6

G F E C B
7 6 5 3 2

Z Z Z 
26 26 26

A A A
1 1 1
```

Basically its just reversing and adding 1 .Or Right shift by 1 all letters.

You can use `ord` for implementing this.

Sample code:

```
x='A'
b=ord(x)+1
print(chr(b))
```

Comment: can you write a python code

Comment: i dont understand can you explain this code input: ABDEF
Output: GFECB

input: ZZZ
output: AAA

input: XTD
output: EUY

input: zzz
output: aaa
Write a program for this scenario

Comment: @jangabramhanandamreddy you can reverse the string and then take `ord` of it and add `1` and convert back to that letter.

Comment: i dont  no about the ord function can you write full code for the AAA to ZZZ

Comment: can you solve this problem today i have text

Comment: @jangabramhanandamreddy It's not up to us to solve your homework. If you don't know a function then look it up in the documentation. Here is the link to the description of [`ord`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#ord).

Comment: @jangabramhanandamreddy these are clues to get the issue solved.Use them to achieve your goal.